# Проблемы с подключением js библиотеки с GitHub

Tags: javascript, github, библиотеки, установка

Вот задался вопросом как подключать свои библиотеки с репозитория? Мой порядок действий таков:

1. залил библиотеку на GitHub
2. открыл там фаил с расширением js
3. скопировал данный URL и занес его в строку http://rawgit.com/
4. прописал данный URL себе в html файл

   ```html
           <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/louisremi/jquery.transform.js/e195b9a7/jquery.transform2d.js"></script>
   ```

и ничего не сработало [image: git проблема]
подскажите, можно ли поправить. Я ведь беру свою библиотеку из своего аккаунта

Comment: попробуйте из гитхаба подключить напрямую, вот так : https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jquery/jquery/master/src/jquery.js

Comment: Собственно вопрос по подключению Своих библиотек со своего аккаунта. Но я попробовал и вами предложенный метод [![2.png](https://s24.postimg.org/fwhg9m4hx/image.png)](https://postimg.org/image/lxf56or41/) Не воспринимает

Comment: adblock может запрещать загрузку этого скрипта

Comment: Не помогло. Addblock здесь не причем